# Jenkins scripted pipeline environment variable

Tags: jenkins, environment-variables, jenkins-pipeline, pipeline

I'm using the Jenkins scripted pipeline and since the last update I get a new warning, which I want to silence, here is an MWE:

```
// FROM https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/examples/#parallel-multiple-nodes

def labels = []

if (Host == 'true') {
    labels.add('<host-slavename>')
}

def builders = [:]

for (x in labels) {
    def label = x

    builders[label] = {
        ansiColor('xterm') {
            node(label) {
                stage('cleanup') {
                    deleteDir()
                }
                stage('build') {
                    def timestamp = sh (script: 'echo -n `(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)`', returnStdout: true)

                    withCredentials([string(credentialsId: 'TEST_PASSWORD', variable: 'PASSWORD')]){

                        sh """
                            logger \
                            TEST_1 "${PASSWORD}" TEST_2 \
                            TEST_3 $timestamp TEST_4
                        """

                        sh '''
                            logger \
                            TEST_1 "$PASSWORD" TEST_2 \
                            TEST_3 $timestamp TEST_4
                        '''
                        
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

parallel builders
```

the first `sh` block returns

```
Warning: A secret was passed to "sh" using Groovy String interpolation, which is insecure.
         Affected argument(s) used the following variable(s): [PASSWORD]
         See https://jenkins.io/redirect/groovy-string-interpolation for details.
+ logger TEST_1 **** TEST_2 TEST_3 20211029074911 TEST_4
```

which at least prints the timestamp and the password (it's censored, but works), but raises the warning.

the second `sh` block returns

```
+ logger TEST_1 **** TEST_2 TEST_3 TEST_4
```

So no warning, but also no timestamp.

Is there a way to write a scripted pipeline that shows no warning, but still the timestamp?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The warning occurs when you use Groovy string interpolation in the first `sh` step like `"${PASSWORD}"` for the reasons explained in [Interpolation of Sensitive Environment Variables](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#interpolation-of-sensitive-environment-variables).

That's why you should always let the shell resolve environment variables as you correctly do in the 2nd `sh` step.

To use non-environment variables like `timestamp`, convert them to environment variables by wrapping the `sh` step in `withEnv` step:

```
withEnv(["timestamp=$timestamp"]) {
    sh '''
        logger \
        TEST_1 "$PASSWORD" TEST_2 \
        TEST_3 $timestamp TEST_4
    '''
}
```

This limits the scope of the environment variable to the `withEnv` block.

Alternatively you could add a member to the `env` map:

```
env.timestamp = sh (script: 'echo -n `(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)`', returnStdout: true)

sh '''
    logger \
    TEST_1 "$PASSWORD" TEST_2 \
    TEST_3 $timestamp TEST_4
'''
```

Comment: The first idea "withEnv" works great for me, thank you. But how can i access  the env.timestamp within the sh? `env.timestamp = sh (script: 'echo -n (date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)', returnStdout: true) sh ''' logger TEST_1 "$PASSWORD" TEST_2 TEST_3 $env.timestamp TEST_4 '''` Does not seem to work.

Comment: @Someone2 Same as with `withEnv`. I've added usage example.